# Oracle 11g (xe) Dump Import from Oracle 11g (orcl) exported dump file

Tags: oracle11g

Oracle dump import throws the following error,

```
Export file created by EXPORT:V11.02.00 via conventional path

Warning: the objects were exported by ......., not by you

import done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
```

Comment: This is not an error, but a warning. By the way, what is your question?

Comment: Import Process not proceeding after this warning

Comment: Does it exit, or does it hang there?

Comment: Hangs here ,import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)

Comment: I have exported the dump file from orcl DB and am trying to import in xe (both Oracle11g)

Comment: How long does it hang there? How large is the export?

Comment: Dump file is 2.48 GB, It hangs for more than 30 mins and i terminated manually